# Unable to open Magento admin interface

Tags: magento

whenever i have opened magento admin interface on linux server. i got the following error :

The connection was reset
The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to see magento logs in

```
{root}/var/log/*
```

and try to increase

```
max_execution_time
```

It might be that your server forbids 18000, which are set in magento's .htaccess

**UPDATE 1**

I Think that the problem is not with magento. It is rather with web server or browser.

Try [this link](http://www.realestatebloglab.com/the-connection-to-the-server-was-reset-while-the-page-was-loading/)

Comment: I have see that max_execution_time in .htaccess file are 18000 and log folder is empty in magento root. but i am still getting the error.       The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your .htaccess file with sample .htaccess file given by Magento.