# I cannot access Magento admin

Tags: magento

I just transfered my magento installation from one local machine server to another linux server. Now, I cannot login to admin panel. When I go to the admin login url, I get the following error message:-

"The connection was reset The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

Some of my module's pages also show this error.

Can anyone please figure out the problem?

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272476/unable-to-open-magento-admin-interface

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following sql statements in your database:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

UPDATE `core_store` SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `core_store_group` SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE `core_website` SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Here in the link to where i had originally found this solution:

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-error-%E2%80%93-notice-undefined-index-0-appcodecoremagecoremodelmysql4config-php-on-line-92/